# DAX custom Grand Total not behaving as expected

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a Measure which calculates a cumulative total:

```
CumulativeCount:=
VAR date1 = MAX( DimDate[Date] )
VAR date2 = MAX( FactTable[EndDate] )
RETURN
CALCULATE (
    SUM( FactTable[Count] ),
    DimDate[Date] <= date1,
    DimDate[Date] <= date2, 
    ALL( DimDate[Date] )
)
```

And another, actually used in the Pivot Table, which, when it's calculating the Grand Total, is supposed to add up the cumulative totals for each date:

```
CumulativeCountForPivot:=
IF (
    -- If calculating for one group
    COUNTROWS( VALUES( FactTable[Group] ) ) = 1,
    -- Do core logic
    [CumulativeCount],
    -- Else add up the results from each group
    SUMX(
        VALUES( FactTable[Group] ),
        [CumulativeCount]
    )
)
```

**I don't understand why the Grand Total in the final column is 12, not 6.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the grand total is for `GroupA` and `GroupB` combined and there is a cumulative count of `12` on that date (`6` for each group).

On `06/01/2017` there are no records for `GroupA` so the `[CumulativeCount]` measure is returning a blank, even though there are records before that date and the count would be `6`. If you added a record for `GroupA` with a `Count` of `0` on `06/01/2017`, then you would see `6` appear.

If you want a measure that only shows `6` on that date, then try something like this:

```
CountForPivot =
    VAR TempTable = SUMMARIZE(FactTable,
                        FactTable[Group],
                        FactTable[EndDate],
                        "Cumulative",
                            CALCULATE(SUM(FactTable[Count]),
                                FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(FactTable, FactTable[Group]),
                                    FactTable[EndDate] <= MAX(FactTable[EndDate])
                                )
                            )
                    )
    RETURN SUMX(TempTable, [Cumulative])
```

Comment: Thank you Alexis for your input. Much appreciated. However the new measure returns 6 for each month, with totals of 6, 12, 12 , 6. Also the **increased complexity** is an issue as I'm already seeing **significant performance issues** with my existing Cumulative logic against the production data. Having just watched a SQLBits SQLBI Dax Performance Tuning video I think I'm going to have to try to pre-calculate the cumulative totals into a calculated table to try to get more use out of the Storage Engine rather than the Formula Engine. Any further help welcome!

Comment: I'd suggest doing the cumulative totals as a calculated column. Definitely more efficient that way since it only has to compute once.